# How can I learn and apply the scientific method in machine learning?

Tags: methodology, methods

**Rigor Theory.** I wish to learn the scientific method and how to apply it in machine learning. Specifically, *how* to verify that a model captured the pattern in data; *how* to rigorously reach conclusions based on well-justified empirical evidence.

**Verification in Practice.** My colleagues in both academia and industry tell me measuring the accuracy of the model on testing data is sufficient, but I don't feel confident such criteria are sufficient.

**Data Science Books.** I have picked up multiple data science books, like [Skiena's manual](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-55444-0), [Dell EMC's book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Data+Science+and+Big+Data+Analytics:+Discovering,+Analyzing,+Visualizing+and+Presenting+Data-p-9781118876138), and [Waikato's data mining](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=1SylCgAAQBAJ&dq=waikato%20data%20mining&source=gbs_navlinks_s). Even though there had been a section for diagnosing the model and measuring results, *my* instinct worries are these are heuristics, but not rigour-based.

**Scientific Method Books.** Searching for the *scientific method* I found, [Statistics and Scientific Method: An Introduction for Students and Researchers](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199543182.001.0001/acprof-9780199543182) and [Principles of Scientific Methods](https://www.routledge.com/Principles-of-Scientific-Methods/Chang/p/book/9781482238099), which seem to answer the crux of my question. I am planning to study both of them.

**My Questions.** Here are couple of questions I hope to gain guidance on, from your wonderful community.

- Is it feasible to rigorously apply the scientific method in machine learning applications like recommendation engines or social sciences, or is it the case that so far our scientific/technological advancement didn't reach that degree of maturity, and that the best we can hope for is heuristics-based approximations.
- Is it feasible to do machine learning in practical industry, by applying the scientific method, or is it the case that industry leaders prefer cheap heuristics in order to minimize a project's costs?
- Are the *scientific method* books I mentioned above useful for enhancing my own skills in machine learning? Are they worthwhile the effort and time?
- Are you aware of better alternative resources for learning the scientific method? Are there more helpful courses or recorded lectures?
- Do you have any recommendations or advise, while studying the scientific method, for someone who is mainly motivated by machine learning in industry like recommendation engines applications and logistical optimization?

Comment: I love this question. I feel like I'm having to discover for myself how to do rigorous work in this aspect; that my department didn't prepare me in that particular aspect of data science. Personally, I've been using tools like Benchling, designed for experimental biologists, to record my ML experiments.

Comment: That is a lot of questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's an excellent idea to acquire and apply a solid scientific basis in general and in ML in particular. Here are a few comments:

- [The scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) is a general set of good principles for obtaining reliable scientific conclusions. It's not especially precise and it's not always clear if it's applied correctly in a specific case, there's no clear binary way to say whether a study satisfies the scientific method or not.
- Mind that what is considered scientifically valid evolves over time. For example, [various shortcomings of using significance tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance#Challenges) have been demonstrated recently.
- In science and in statistics in particular, the main scientific point is usually not to prove something with 100% confidence (virtually never possible) but to quantify the confidence in some reliable way. A common mistake is to expect a ML prediction to be 100% reliable: of course this is not possible (it wouldn't be statistical learning otherwise), but it is possible to measure how likely a prediction is correct (to some extent).
- So the level of maturity of the field doesn't matter: solid scientific principles can be applied to any existing method. This even applies to heuristics: it's just a matter of estimating their performance reliably.
- Last point: let's not forget that the scientific method is not a rigid set of formal rules to apply systematically, it's also about questioning whether a particular dataset or approach is adapted to the goal. Another common mistake I see is to apply a specific kind of evaluation to a system without thinking whether this evaluation truly measures the task that the system is supposed to do.

(I don't have any specific book recommendation)

Comment: Thanks! As a plus, Would you recommend some references for learning how to evaluate confidence in models?